# Multiple JOIN on the same table TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

After a search about my doubt, around a lot of questions about this I still can't get the result I want.
I'm trying to join the same table 3 times but Sqlserver is not recognizing the fields.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetServices
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        [Service].ServiceID AS ServiceID,
        [Service].ServiceStart AS [Data de ínicio do serviço],
        EE.EntDescr AS Entidade,
        EE1.PartnerID AS Parceiro,
        EE2.Partner2ID AS [Segundo Parceiro],
        Circuit.CircuitDescr AS [Descrição do Circuito],
        Truck.TruckPlate AS Matrícula,
        [Service].StartKms AS [Km's Iniciais],
        [Service].StartCheck1 AS [Verificação 1],
        [Service].StartCheck2 AS [Verificação 2],
        [Service].StartCheck3 AS [Verificação 3],
        [Service].StartCheck4 AS [Verificação 4],
        [Service].StartCheck5 AS [Verificação 5],
        [Service].StartCheck6 AS [Verificação 6],
        [Service].ServiceEnd AS [Data de ínicio do serviço],
        [Service].EndKms AS [Km's Finais],
        [Service].HRCheck AS [Verificação HR],
        [Service].HRNotes AS [Notas HR]
    FROM
     [Service]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EntEnt EE ON EE.EntID = [Service].DriverID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EntEnt EE1 ON EE1.EntID = [Service].PartnerID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EntEnt EE2 ON EE2.EntID = [Service].Partner2ID
    INNER JOIN Circuit on Circuit.CircuitID = [Service].CircuitID
    INNER JOIN Truck ON Truck.TruckID = [Service].TruckID
END
```

**EE1.PartnerID AS Parceiro && EE2.Partner2ID AS [Segundo Parceiro],** is getting an Invalid column name error

Comment: Does EntEnt table really have those 2 _columns_?

Comment: it would probably help if we could see the structure of the tables

Comment: You can also create a function and pass the parameters to it to get the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetServices
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        [Service].ServiceID AS ServiceID,
        [Service].ServiceStart AS [Data de ínicio do serviço],
        EE.EntDescr AS Entidade,
        Service.PartnerID AS Parceiro,
        Service.Partner2ID AS [Segundo Parceiro],
        Circuit.CircuitDescr AS [Descrição do Circuito],
        Truck.TruckPlate AS Matrícula,
        [Service].StartKms AS [Km's Iniciais],
        [Service].StartCheck1 AS [Verificação 1],
        [Service].StartCheck2 AS [Verificação 2],
        [Service].StartCheck3 AS [Verificação 3],
        [Service].StartCheck4 AS [Verificação 4],
        [Service].StartCheck5 AS [Verificação 5],
        [Service].StartCheck6 AS [Verificação 6],
        [Service].ServiceEnd AS [Data de ínicio do serviço],
        [Service].EndKms AS [Km's Finais],
        [Service].HRCheck AS [Verificação HR],
        [Service].HRNotes AS [Notas HR]
    FROM
     [Service]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EntEnt EE ON EE.EntID = [Service].DriverID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EntEnt EE1 ON EE1.EntID = [Service].PartnerID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EntEnt EE2 ON EE2.EntID = [Service].Partner2ID
    INNER JOIN Circuit on Circuit.CircuitID = [Service].CircuitID
    INNER JOIN Truck ON Truck.TruckID = [Service].TruckID
END
```

// I think your using wring table. replace EE1 to Service might be work

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query the two fields you query should be ee1.EntID and EE2.entID Because Partner1ID and Partner2ID are in your service table

Comment: This should be a comment.  If you don't have sufficient rep to comment, then either give a full answer or don't say anything :-)